# Bean creation intercepter

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

Let asy that there are several `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` classes in the application which creatred like that:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("one")
public WebClient one() {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("someUrl").build();
}
@Bean
@Qualifier("two")
public WebClient two() {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("someUrl").build();
}
//etc.
```

It is needed to add filters for all create `WebClient`s. Some thing like that:

```
public WebClient intercepter(WebClient webClient) {
    return webClient.mutate().filter(setupFilter());
}
```

Can this be possible with spring 5?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't have permissions to modify the code of beans provided?

In that case you can implement a BeanPostProcessor - detect WebClient implementations (or methods by return type) and return updated value in each method.

Alternatively you can replace the real implementation of WebClient with the decorator in your post-processor.

[Here is the example](https://github.com/azee/loki/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/greatbit/loki/LockBeanPostProcessor.java) of how to implement a processor. In this case Locking operations are being injected into original methods.

Don't forget to [include your post processor to the context](https://github.com/azee/loki/blob/master/src/test/resources/beans.xml#L12)